# Weighted L infinity norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand weighted Lebesgue spaces.
For $a\geq 0$, let consider the space $W_a$ of all measurable vector fields $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that
$$
\| f \|_{W_a} = \mathrm{ess \, sup}_{x\in \mathbb{R^3}} |x|^a f(x) < \infty.
$$
Some questions that I am trying to solve are:

1. For which values of $a\geq 0$ the quantity $\| f \|_{W_a}$ is finite ?
2. If $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$, for which values of $a\geq 0$ the quantity $\| f \|_{W_a}$ is finite ?
3. is it possible to prove that if $a>b$, then $W_a \subset W_b$ ?

Until now I tried to attack 3 considering that if $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$, then
$$ |x|^a=|x|^b|x|^{r}, $$
where $r$ is such that $a=b+r$.

Do you have any reference where I can read more about this kind of spaces ?

Comment: Maybe it is more instructive to construct vector fields that are not in $W_a$ for some given $a$? Try vector fields that are zero on the unit ball, and vector fields that are zero outside the unit ball. Can this vector fields be unbounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that $W_a$ is just the space of functions $f$ such that $f(x) \leq C/|x|^a$ for some constant $C$.

1. This question is badly formulated, it will depend on $f$. For example if $f$ is bounded and compactly supported, then $\|f\|_{W^a}$ is always finite, but if $f=1$, then $f$ is infinite as soon as $a>0$.
2. Again, $\|f\|_{W^a}$ is finite for any $f\in L^\infty$ only if $a=0$, as you can notice by taking $f=1$.
3. No, in general, $f(x) \leq C/|x|^a$ does not imply $f(x) \leq C/|x|^b$ for another value $b\neq a$. Take for example $f(x) = 1/|x|^a$, then $f\in W_a$ but not in $W_b$ for any other $b$.

Comment: The constant $C$ that you mentioned does not depend of $X$, isn' t it ?

Comment: It doesn't depend on $x$ indeed.

Comment: do you have any idea about where find references for learning more about these functional spaces ?