# References on weighted L infinity spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730786/weighted-l-infinity-norm) I posted a question about wighted $L^\infty$ spaces. These functional spaces can be defined as: for $a\geq 0$, let consider the space $W_a$ of all measurable vector fields $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that
$$
\| f \|_{W_a} = \mathrm{ess \, sup}_{x\in \mathbb{R^3}} |x|^a f(x) < \infty.
$$

**Do you know some references where I can find the main properties of these weighted spaces ?**

Comment: @LL 3.14 do you have any idea about it ?